# How to access the URL parameters from any Angular component?

Tags: angular, angular-router, angular-activatedroute

I have an app whose components are structured as below:

```
1. Fam.Component
1.1. Header.Component <------ Unable access param from here
1.2. ParentGrid.Component
1.2.1. ChildGrid.Component
1.2.1.1 GrandChildGrid.Component <----- Can access from here!!
```

Clicking on an item in the parent grid, will load the child grid relevant to that item.

At the grand child level, my browser URL looks something like this:

```
http://onebigfamily.com/Fam/Parents/1/Children/23/GrandChildren
```

this will basically show all the grandchildren for the 23rd Child of the 1st parent.

the path for this URL in my routing config looks is like this:

```
Fam/Parents/:parentId/Children/childId:/GrandChildren
```

I can access the `childId` and `parentId` param values by navigating the `ActivatedRoute` from my `GrandChildren` component by doing a simple `this.route.snapshot.params['childId']` (of course for parent ID have to traverse up the route tree).

**Now to the question...**

How can I access the `:childId` and `:parentId` from my Header Component? these values are showing up as undefined when i do a `this.route.snapshot.params['childId']`?

I just need to access the parent ID and the child ID as long as they are in the URL, regardless of which component has the control.

Comment: Have you read Angular docs about routing?? Its explained very well there

Answer (score 1):

You can access child route via `firstChild`, so (depending on your routes config), it might look like this:

`this.route.snapshot.firstChild.firstChild.params['childId']`

Answer (score 0):

You can get the url params in the route variable

```
this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
                var parentId = params['parentId'];
                var childId = params['childId'];
 });
```

Comment: my question is about doing this from separate components.

Answer (score -1):

Since you want to check route params that are different than @ your header creation time you have to subscribe to route changes and get params from change events. In your header component you have to do:

```
  this.route.paramMap
    .subscribe(params => {
         //assign params here
    });
```

where `route` is injected `ActivatedRoute`
from docs

> params—An Observable that contains the required and optional
>   parameters specific to the route. Use paramMap instead.

The reason why it is not working for you is beacause your header comonent (parent) has different creation time then your child components, so route snapshot is just like that - route snapshot from the moment header is created.